# Download XML File From Oracle Database

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

I Have save my XML file to oracle database successful with C#.Net 4
and now i would like to download that file, here is the code:

```
    public bool DwndData(object id, out DataTable data, out string message)
    {
        _dataadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        _dataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT DT_XML FROM EKG.MY_TABLE WHERE ID=:MY_ID";
        _dataadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(":MY_ID", id);
        try
        {
            data = new DataTable("MY DOWNLOAD");
            _dataadapter.Fill(data);
            message = "Get data success.";
            return true;
        }
        catch (OracleException e)
        {
            data = null;
            message = "Get data Error.\n MSG :" + e.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }

private void CreateFile(object FileValue)
{
    string strpath = @"D:\MyData\Example.xml";
    FileStream fs;
    int longfile = ObjectToByteArray(FileValue).Length;
    if (!Directory.Exists(strpath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(strpath));
        fs = new FileStream(@strpath, FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(ObjectToByteArray(FileValue), 1000, longfile);
        fs.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        fs = new FileStream(@strpath, FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(ObjectToByteArray(FileValue), 1000, longfile);
        fs.Close();
    }
}


private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}


private void download_data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable ds_dt;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow cell in datagridview1.SelectedRows)
    {
        if (!DwndData(datagridview1.Rows[cell.Index].Cells["ID"].Value, out ds_dt, out msg))
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        if (ds_dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            CreateFile(ds_dt.Rows[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: system.data.datarow is not marked as serializable

Comment: That is not a question

Comment: Create a class inherited from datarow which implements serializable.

Comment: Hmmmmm... that is the error message, how could resolve that problem.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ds_dt.Rows[0]` returns a row. You need the item in the row using `Item`

```
ds_dt.Rows[0].Item["DT_XML"]
```

and pass that into CreateFile.

See [here for more doco on DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also try replacing the CreateFile function with

```
private void CreateFile(string data)
{
    string strpath = @"D:\MyData\Example.xml";
    File.WriteAllText(strPath, data);
}
```

calling it like this:

```
CreateFile(ds_dt.Rows[0].ItemArray["DT_XML"].ToString());
```

Comment: there is no ds_dt.Rows[0].Item["DT_XML"] but ds_dt.Rows[0].ItemArray["DT_XML"]; it's work.. but some content of my xml file is broken actually syntax <xml> </xml>

Comment: sorry i mean like this: ÿÿÿÿØ€<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> the correct content is <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> how to resolve that.